# C code pthread semaphore program with 3 threads that prints in sequence

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I want to print sequence like 1,2,3,1,2,3...But the below code is not printing in this order. I am not able to understand where I am making mistake in using semaphore. Please help me in understanding the mistake I am making in this code so that I can fix it.

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_NUM 50
sem_t sem1, sem2, sem3;

void *f1(void*)
{
  sem_wait(&sem1);  
  for(int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++)
  {
    printf("\nF1(): %d", 1);
    sem_post(&sem2);         
  }  
}

void* f2(void*)
{
  sem_wait(&sem2);  
  for(int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++)
  {
     printf("\nF2(): %d", 2);
     sem_post(&sem3);
  }
}

void* f3(void*)
{
  sem_wait(&sem3);
  for(int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++)
  {
    printf("\nF3(): %d", 3);    
    sem_post(&sem1);   
 }
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t p1, p2, p3;
   sem_init(&sem1, 0, 1);
   sem_init(&sem2, 0, 1);
   sem_init(&sem3, 0, 1); 

  pthread_create(&p1, NULL, f1,  (void*)NULL);
  pthread_create(&p2, NULL, f2,  (void*)NULL);
  pthread_create(&p3, NULL, f3,  (void*)NULL);  

  pthread_join(p1, NULL);
  pthread_join(p2, NULL);
  pthread_join(p3, NULL);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You initialize all of the semaphores the same way, and use them all the same way; why would you expect `F1` to print first?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `sem1` differently from the others so that `F1` gets past its initial `sem_wait` first.

Also note that once each function enters its loop, it never calls `sem_wait` again, which means you have no more control of the order of printing.

Comment: In particular, semaphores `sem2` and `sem3` need to be initialized with a semaphore value of 0, so that functions `f2()` and `f3()` do not initially proceed.  `sem1` could also be initialized that way, for symmetry and consistency, provided that the main thread posted to `sem1`, once, to let `f1()` proceed the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was able to find the issue and fixed the code

Answer (score 0):

Intialize the sem2 and sem3 with 0 and Put sem_wait(...) call inside loop in all functions.I hope below code gives the expected results 123123...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define MAX_NUM 50
sem_t sem1, sem2, sem3;

void *f1(void* p)
{
  for(int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++)
  {
  sem_wait(&sem1);
    printf("\nF1(): %d", 1);
    sem_post(&sem2);
  }
}

void *f2(void* p)
{
  for(int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++)
  {
  sem_wait(&sem2);
     printf("\nF2(): %d", 2);
     sem_post(&sem3);
  }
}

void *f3(void* p)
{
  for(int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++)
  {
  sem_wait(&sem3);
    printf("\nF3(): %d", 3);
    sem_post(&sem1);
 }
}


int main()
{
   pthread_t p1, p2, p3;
   sem_init(&sem1, 0, 1);
   sem_init(&sem2, 0, 0);
   sem_init(&sem3, 0, 0);

  pthread_create(&p1, NULL, f1,  (void*)NULL);
  pthread_create(&p2, NULL, f2,  (void*)NULL);
  pthread_create(&p3, NULL, f3,  (void*)NULL);
  pthread_join(p1, NULL);
  pthread_join(p2, NULL);
  pthread_join(p3, NULL);

  return 0;

}
```